# QML save image file on device

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have successfully downloaded image file from web by sending it with base64 from server. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441805/how-to-save-the-image-to-a-file-in-qml) tutorial to save that image on the device, but I need to specify the image directory according to different devices so I used the `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation)` as the saveURL. The issue is that the directory returned looks like

`/data/data/org.qtproject.example.WierszeApp/files/.local/share/libWierszeApp.so`

and there is no way to read saved file. Also calling `.cdUp()` on the dir returns false as it's probably non readable/writable. What makes me dizzy is why does it return a file with `.so` extension? When I save it to hardcoded location like `/sdcard/Download/` then I have no trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the horse's mouth:

> The storage location returned can be a directory that does not exist; i.e., it may need to be created by the system or the user."

There's nothing wrong with naming a directory with a `.so` extension. It's just the scheme that Qt has chosen, for whatever reason.

Comment: `assets:/qml/WierszeApp/main.qml:94:5: QML Image: Cannot open: file://data/data/org.qtproject.example.WierszeApp/files/.local/share/libWierszeApp.so/i2.png` is what I get when i call `source: "file:/" + path + "/i2.png"` where path is the `QStandardPaths::...` expression

Comment: @Nadarian Have you created the path as the documentation suggests?

Comment: Ok, I didn't get what you mean at first. Thank you, it was quite a bit struggle for me

Comment: Actually if you could give me an advice of what am I now doing wrong? I have my path in `QDir mypath(QStandardPaths...)` variable. I check whether it exists `if(!mypath.exists())` if it doesn't I do `mypath.mkpath(".")` and it returns true but every time I launch the application the `if()` statement executes as if the dir was not created

Comment: Perhaps your development environment doesn't keep those files around? I don't know much about Qt on Android.